# Transpose of rows and columns using pivot in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

```
select planttype ,sum(noof50kgsbags*50)[50 Kg],sum(noof70kgsbags*70)[70 Kg]
from K_FeedPlantEntryIndent
WHERE  (date BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND getdate()) AND (attrited = 'True')
group by planttype order by planttype
```

**OutPut::**

```
planttype   [50 Kg Bags]
Rohini        56150
Sneha         43950
KJL           353550
Suguna       1290850
```

**Desired Output::**

```
Bags    Rohini   Sneha   KJL   Suguna
 50KgBags    x        xx     xx    xxx
```

**My Query using Pivot::**

```
select * from (select planttype  ,sum(noof50kgsbags*50)[50 Kg] from       K_FeedPlantEntryIndent WHERE  (date BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND getdate()) AND   (attrited = 'True')
group by planttype)as t
PIVOT
( sum([50 Kg])
for[planttype] in( Rohini,Sneha,KJL,Suguna )
) As t2
```

**Result for this query:**

```
    Rohini   Sneha   KJL   Suguna
     x        xx     xx    xxx
```

I need  Bags also by doing I am getting error . Please Help me out

Comment: can you provide an error message?

Comment: @Andrey  not exactly a specified error I am getting different O/P

Comment: let me clarify: your problem is that you are missing the Bags column?

Comment: @Andrey Yes. By adding Bags column I am getting different out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select '50KgBags' [Bags], * from (select planttype  ,sum(noof50kgsbags*50)[50 Kg] from       K_FeedPlantEntryIndent WHERE  (date BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND getdate()) AND   (attrited = 'True')
group by planttype)as t
PIVOT
( sum([50 Kg])
for[planttype] in( Rohini,Sneha,KJL,Suguna )
) As t2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72fb7/1)